# How can I reference multiple foreign key in one table to a single primary key in ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I tried this query and it doesn't work. Says that I must use ON DELETE NO ACTION, but I need to set null for deleted references

```
CREATE TABLE airports
(
    id integer primary key identity(1,1),
    country varchar(50) not null,
    city varchar(50) not null,
    airport_name varchar(50) not null,
    airport_class varchar(50) not null
);

CREATE TABLE flights
(
    id integer primary key identity(1,1),
    code integer unique not null,
    departure_point integer,
    arrival_point integer,
    departure_time datetime not null,
    arrival_time datetime not null,
    foreign key(departure_point) references airports(id) on delete set null,
    foreign key(arrival_point) references airports(id) on delete set null
);
```

The error (it's in russian, sorry)

```
Введение ограничения внешнего ключа (FOREIGN KEY) "FK__flights__arrival__286302EC" для таблицы "flights" может привести к появлению циклов или множественных каскадных путей. Укажите ON DELETE NO ACTION или ON UPDATE NO ACTION либо измените другие ограничения внешнего ключа (FOREIGN KEY).
```

Comment: Hi antttzey. Can you include the error verbatim in your question please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if I create separate tables with two columns: one is primary and a foreign key references a flight, and another is regular foreign key references an airport.

Here is my database diagram:

[image: database diagram]

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment.

I don't think this is possible in SQL Server.  Unfortunately, SQL Server only allows one `set null` per foreign table reference.

That said, you might have other options:

- I'm not sure that having `flights` with `NULL` airports is actually useful.  You might want to delete the entire row.
- If you liked, you could stash the flight information in an archive table, with `NULL` values or invalid foreign key references.
- You can soft delete the airports.  Just have a flag for whether the airport is active.